# Error creating form

Tags: delphi-7

Estou desenvolvendo um programa no Delphi e conectando no banco de dados, no banco tem apenas uma tabela. Hoje fui tentar abrir o form e apareceu a seguinte mensagem:

> Error creating form:Datasource makes a circular link

Comment: Talvez o erro esteja na ligação dos componentes de acesso a dados. Se possível copie e cole aqui os componentes para vermos as propriedades.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Provavelmente você esta linkando o DataSource a um DataSet que esta ligado a outro DataSet, reveja a ordem de criação dos componentes:

```
Conexão => DataSet => (Provider + DataSet, caso existir) => DataSource
```